# h2 concurrent update in embedded mode

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm using Hibernate 1.4.191 along with Hibernate 4.3.1. My h2 connection url is  `dbc:h2:file:./h2/myDB` - which is an embedded DB without `MULTI_THREADED` enabled. I'm running with MVCC on - as this is the default setting for 1.4.191.

Using this configuration in my application, I got the following stack trace while trying to execute an update HQL statement:

```
2017-07-11 19:38:48 SEVERE Could not set rounding style. org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect$2.convert(H2Dialect.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:118)
    at de.oktopos.dataBase.receipts.converter.ReceiptConverter$29.runOperation(ReceiptConverter.java:1214)
    at de.oktopos.dataBase.receipts.converter.ReceiptConverter$29.runOperation(ReceiptConverter.java:1210)
    at de.oktopos.dataBase.tools.DatabaseOperationRunner.run(DatabaseOperationRunner.java:71)
    at de.oktopos.dataBase.receipts.converter.ReceiptConverter.setRoundingStyle(ReceiptConverter.java:1226)
    at de.oktopos.dataBase.receipts.converter.ReceiptCacheWriter.setRoundingStyle(ReceiptCacheWriter.java:99)
    at de.oktopos.oktoDeskService.remote.OktoDeskModel.setRoundingStyle(OktoDeskModel.java:841)
    at net.oktopos.cashdesk.DeskModelProcessor.setRoundingStyle(DeskModelProcessor.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Zeitüberschreitung beim Versuch die Tabelle  zu sperren
Timeout trying to lock table ; SQL statement:
update Receipt set turnoverType=? [50200-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.command.Command.filterConcurrentUpdate(Command.java:307)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:260)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Gleichzeitige Änderung in Tabelle "RECEIPT": eine andere Transaktion hat den gleichen Datensatz geändert oder gelöscht
Concurrent update in table "RECEIPT": another transaction has updated or deleted the same row [90131-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.convertException(MVTable.java:898)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.remove(MVSecondaryIndex.java:247)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.removeRow(MVTable.java:677)
    at org.h2.table.Table.updateRows(Table.java:487)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Update.update(Update.java:145)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entry is locked [1.4.191/101]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:773)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap.set(TransactionStore.java:1031)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap.remove(TransactionStore.java:989)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.remove(MVSecondaryIndex.java:241)
    ... 37 more
```

Im trying to understand how this is possible. The stack trace seems to say that a lock [could not be acquired because of another connection (50200)](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html#c50200). In particular it says that [another connection concurrently updated the table (90131)](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html#c90131). But there can only be one connection because the database is embedded. Am I missing something here?

The the HQL query is basically executed as follows (minus error handling boilerplate, DBReceipt maps to receipt):

```
   Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
   session.createQuery("UPDATE DBReceipt SET turnovertype = :turnovertype")
                        .setParameter("turnovertype", turnovertype)
                        .executeUpdate();
   transaction.commit();
   session.close();
```

There are of course many other database writes/reads in the background on different threads, but all use the same connection.

The error kept happening when the above part of the code was called. Even restarting the application did not help - the next call of the code would cause the same exception. Only dropping the DB helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found the likely source of the problem after looking arround a bit in my code base.

I was namely creating a `LockRequest` and locking the a receipt in the receipt table. If this lock is never let go (because the transaction ends up in an infinite loop), then any update on the receipt table afterwards would lead to the stack trace above.

I solved the problem by removing the `LockRequest` (I couldn't find the source of the infinite loop). This was possible because we recently moved to locking that receipt on an application level, and also because there would be no problems in our application with optimistic locking.

Another work around to this problem would be to add a timeout to the lock, transaction, or session. However, my enviroment doesn't seem to support any of these - at least none of them worked in my tests.